# bluetooth connects then disconnects 20.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, 20.04, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

On Ubuntu 20.04, I've tried using bluetoothctl to turn things on and off, as well as rfkill. The device tries to connect, 'succeeds' for a few seconds and then encounters an error.

```
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 RSSI: -46
...
[bluetooth]# connect 00:6A:8E:17:14:76
Attempting to connect to 00:6A:8E:17:14:76
...
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 Connected: yes

...

[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:6A:8E:17:14:76 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

(Manually deleted all the devices it detects but aren't mine, 00:6A:8E:17:14:76)
It claims to have connected, my headphones beep, then it prints the UUIDs all at once and fails because of some error. (Before the headphones would beep twice in different pitches when they worked)

I struggled with this in 18.04, i upgraded to 20.04 and it seemed to work but eventually it stopped working again. Multiple resets, rfkill, bluetoothctl etc. didnt work. Uninstalling then reinstalling bluez didnt work. I'd appreciate troubleshooting instructions other than this. Thank you!

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    1.910005] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   27.667675] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   27.667697] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   27.667699] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   27.667701] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   27.667703] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   28.131838] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   28.132853] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   28.132854] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   28.188011] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   28.188029] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   28.188033] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[   28.989897] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[   49.341932] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   49.341934] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   49.351432] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  139.520622] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  139.520628] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  139.520633] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1629.988518] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

this command shows that i have a realtek 8723 bluetooth adapter, kernel version 5.4.0-40-generic